# Button hide in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms PCL .

> I have button and entry in one layout on the same grid position.Is there a way to hide a button but its click function has to work.

Comment: If you detect the button click, then Entry functionality will be collapsed. You can't edit the text. Can you explain your scenario? Why you need to trigger event in Button click?

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks for your reply.

I solved by myself by setting opacity to 0 i.e Opacity="0" for button.so that it will not display but its functionalities will work as normal.